# Getting wrong position of list items even list is sorted alphabetically

Tags: android, sorting, listview

i have a list coming from AWS and list was showing as per the DB,and click listeners was also working fine. (Like if i click on New-York, It will be showing New-York details) but after sorting with comparator, the list is coming alphabetically ..but when i click on 1st item it is showing some other city details.

First activity code

```
 List<SettlementsTable> lstSettlements = new ArrayList<>();
            lstSettlements.addAll((List<SettlementsTable>) result);
            for (final SettlementsTable table : lstSettlements)

                lstStrings.add(table.getAreaName());

                adapter = new SettlementListAdapter(lstStrings, getApplicationContext());


                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String s, String t1) {
                    return s.compareTo(t1);
                }
            });
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    SettlementsTable settlementsTable = lstSettlements.get(i);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SettlementsActivity.this, SettlementListResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("KEY", (Serializable) settlementsTable);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Second Activity code

```
 settlementsTable = (SettlementsTable) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("KEY");

    toolbar.setTitle(settlementsTable.getAreaName());
    population = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    establishYear=  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

     population.setText(settlementsTable.getPopulation_2015());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i click on 1st item it is showing some other city details.

Because `Comparator` is used on Adapter instance instead of `lstSettlements`. `onItemClick` return position according to sorted data-source which is  `lstStrings`.

Get right AreaName name as :

```
     String strAreaName=(String)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

and to get `SettlementsTable` object in `onItemClick`, pass it to Adapter and then apply sorting on Adapter and get item as:

```
     SettlementsTable selectedObj=(SettlementsTable)
                                      adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

Comment: Hello sir.. can you please tell me where to replace this code?? I am messed up now  so please can you help me with the code? thanks ...sorry but m not able to tag